# Multiple languages for page (react-i18next)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

I am using react-i18next lib for languages.

**Problem**: I need to use user language for website but for article i need to use language of this article.

**My solution**: I want to wrap current article in another I18nextProvider and pass article lang to it. I hope it will be fine:) If it's works i will write solution here.

**My question**: Maybe exists another solution of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's works:

```
export const LanguageContainer: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
  const i18n = React.useMemo(() => {
    const xhr = new XHR(undefined, {
      loadPath: (languages, namespace) => {
        const version = app.Version ? `?v=${app.Version}` : '';
        const dir = app.Production ? Configuration.Localization.RootDir : Configuration.Localization.DefaultRootDir;
        return url.resolve(dir, `./${props.lang}/${namespace}.json${version}`);
      },
    });
    const I18n = i18next.createInstance().use(xhr);

    I18n.init({
      ns: ['general'],
      defaultNS: 'general',
      fallbackLng: Configuration.Localization.DefaultLanguage,
      whitelist: Configuration.Localization.Languages.map((x) => x.key),
    });

    return I18n;
  }, [props.lang]);

  return (
    <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
      {props.children}
    </I18nextProvider>
  );
};
```

And how to use:

```
<LanguageContainer lang="en">
   // here components which need to use lang en     
</LanguageContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<LanguageContainer lang=({language})>
  // here components which need to use lang en     
</LanguageContainer>
```

This is the best away, because this value is object who you send from customers components  . And not bad idea in this case use context

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution to get additional languages is to call `i18n.getFixedT('language-code')`.